# How to resolve MongoDB Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.6fodeir.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Am trying to npm start my backend but I am having the error with connection to mongodb atlas. here is my index.js code:

```
import express from "express"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const app = express();
dotenv.config();


const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
        });
        console.log("connected to mongodb")
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
};


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world")
})


mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
  console.log("monogDB disconnected")
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("monogDB connected")
});



app.listen(3000, () => {
    connect()
    console.log("connected to backend!")
})
```

**And my Mongo_URL** = "mongodb://Booking:@cluster0.6fodeir.mongodb.net/Booking?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

**I have also whitelisted my IP adress and change DNS but nothing works for me please tell my how to resolve this issue :(**